# Overloading the standard operator<< for std::complex

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, eigen

Is there any way of replacing the default

```
template <typename T, typename charT, typename traits> 
std::basic_ostream<charT, traits> &
operator << (std::basic_ostream<charT, traits> &strm, const std::complex<T>& c)
```

that comes with the standard library with my own version? I cannot just overload it using the above signature, since the compiler complains (and it is right) about ambiguous call. I need such an overload as I'd like to display `std::complex` numbers in a different format, like `a + b*i`, instead of the default `(a,b)`.

I can simply do this

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::complex<T>& c)
{
    os << real(z) << " + " << imag(z) << "i";
    return os;
}
```

however this is not the generic version used in `std`, and won't be called by other libraries, such as Eigen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do -- at least because you are already willing to take the officially forbidden approach to add something to `namespace std` which is not related to a user-defined class -- is to explicitly specialize  it for the types you require.

```
template <typename charT, typename traits>
std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
operator << (std::basic_ostream<charT, traits> &strm, const std::complex<double>& c)    
{
    strm<<c.real()<<"+"<<c.imag()<<"*i";
    return strm;
}
```

The compiler will then pick the perfect match rather than the templated version. Overload it for each type you need.

Note however that following the C++ standard, this produces undefined behaviour, as you may not add anything to `namespace std` which replaces already existing implementations.

Still, it seems to work at least on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/e.js/piVPK3) using the g++ compiler, and probably that is the same for other modern compilers [this guess is based on [this thread here](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.c++/specializing-std-less/1015688)]

Comment: Thanks, it compiles and works, but, if I use for example `std::cout << eigen_matrix`, where `eigen_matrix` is a matrix from Eigen3 library, it still displays them in the old format. Eigen matrices overload `operator<<` to display complex matrices, however somehow inside the overload they still call the `std::ostream& operator<<`. This is the main issue I have, as I am interested in displaying these matrices without writing another custom display function. PS: the matrices are over `complex<double>`, so in principle the complex numbers should be displayed using the overload, but it's not so.

Comment: It may have to do with ADL actually, will investigate, as the `operator<<` for matrices is declared in `Eigen` namespace, and will first find the `std` overload for `std::complex`, at least that's my guess...

Comment: YEAP, this was what happened, if I surround the definition above by `namespace Eigen{ ... }`, it works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: You can also just not put your operator in namespace std, and it works just as well, thus avoiding undefined behaviour. E.G. http://ideone.com/AQaB2X